# How to explain curvature of spacetime at the time of big bang

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, curvature, big-bang

According to Einstein mass causes curvature of spacetime ,so he basically defined mass using space i.e (mass is something which causes curvature of spacetime).Now at the time of bigbang there was no space (i.e if big bang is rapid expansion of space then definitely there is no space to experience curvature because of the high energy and mass).How to explain this 
To put everything in simple statement...what'S outside what we call space? or what is absence of space?

Comment: This question assumes too much of what is definitely not Scientific. I'd recommend the OP to scroll this website and the internet, for getting some insights.

Answer (score 0):

The Big Bang singularity predicted by General Relativity is un-physical due to divergent physical quantities like density and curvature. Therefore the Big Bang theory starts at $t = 0$ with a hot and dense state of Planck scale and from this point on the universe expands according to GR.

Comment: sorry,I don't get it

Comment: If  the mass would exist in a point as predicted by General Relativity, the density would be infinite. This is unphysical however, which means that GR brakes down. Physics requires a well defined state. Going back in time the very early universe was hot and dense, from here on the physical evaluation starts. Questions like 'what was before' can't be answered by physics.